# Separar string por caracteres

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

Buen día, he estado intentando separar el siguiente dataframe:

```
0   1. Mirazur de Mauro Colagreco (Francia)
1   2. Restaurante Noma 2.0 de René Redzepi (Dinam...
2   3. Asador Etxebarri de Víctor Arguinzoniz (Esp...
3   4. Gaggan de Gaggan Anand (Tailandia)
4   5. Geranium de Rasmus Kofoed (Dinamarca)
5   6. Central de Virgilio Martinez (Perú)
6   7. Mugaritz de Andoni Luis Aduriz (España)
7   8. L’Arpege de Alain Passard (Francia)
8   9. Disfrutar de Oriol Castro, Eduard Xatruch y...
9   10. Maido de Mitsuharu Tsumura (Perú)
10  11. Den de Zaiyu Hasegawa (Japón)
```

Necesito vuestra ayuda para separarlo en columnas **"Ranking"**, **"Restaurant"**, **"Chef"** y **"País"**.

He intentado `str.split` pero no logro separarlos en la manera que quiero.

`data["Ranking"]= data[0].str.split(".", n=1, expand=True)`. Obtengo el Ranking del restaurante, ejm: **1**

`data["Restaurant"]= data[0].str.split("de", n=1, expand=True)`. Obtengo el Nombre del restaurante pero con la posición también, ejm: **1. Mirazur**

`data["País"]= data[0].str.split("(", n=0, expand=True)`. Obtengo toda la cadena de texto hasta el separador "(". Ejm: **1. Mirazur de Mauro Colagreco**, pero lo que quiero obtener es solo el país **Francia**.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vez de `pandas.Series.str.split`, creo que es mucho más simple usar `pandas.Series.str.extract` y una expresión regular:

```
import re
import pandas as pd


datos = [
    '1. Mirazur de Mauro Colagreco (Francia)',
    '2. Restaurante Noma 2.0 de René Redzepi (Dinamarca)',
    '3. Asador Etxebarri de Víctor Arguinzoniz (España)',
    '4. Gaggan de Gaggan Anand (Tailandia)',
    '5. Geranium de Rasmus Kofoed (Dinamarca)',
    '6. Central de Virgilio Martinez (Perú)',
    '7. Mugaritz de Andoni Luis Aduriz (España)',
    '8. L’Arpege de Alain Passard (Francia)']

df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
df = df[0].str.extract(r"""
    ^
    (?P<Ranking>\d+)   # Primera columna
    \.\W+
    (?P<Restaurant>.+) # Segunda columna
    \W+de\W+
    (?P<Chef>.+)       # Tercera columna
    \W+\(
    (?P<País>.+)       # Cuarta columna
    \)
    $
    """, flags=re.VERBOSE
    )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>   Ranking            Restaurant                Chef       País
> 0       1               Mirazur     Mauro Colagreco    Francia
> 1       2  Restaurante Noma 2.0        René Redzepi  Dinamarca
> 2       3      Asador Etxebarri  Víctor Arguinzoniz     España
> 3       4                Gaggan        Gaggan Anand  Tailandia
> 4       5              Geranium       Rasmus Kofoed  Dinamarca
> 5       6               Central   Virgilio Martinez       Perú
> 6       7              Mugaritz  Andoni Luis Aduriz     España
> 7       8              L’Arpege       Alain Passard    Francia
> ```

La expresión:

- `^` -> afirma la posición al comienzo de una línea
- `(\d+)` -> Grupo de captura

  - `\d` -> coincide con un dígito (igual a [0-9])
  - `+` -> Cuantificador: coincide entre una e ilimitadas veces, tantas veces como sea posible, devolviendo según sea necesario (codicioso).
- `\.` ->  coincide con el carácter "." literalmente.
- `\W` -> clase de caracteres, coincide con cualquier carácter que no sea de palabra.
  veces como sea posible, devolviendo según sea necesario (codicioso)
- `(.+)` -> Grupo de captura

  - `.` -> coincide con cualquier carácter (excepto los terminadores de línea)
  - `+` Cuantificador: coincide entre una e ilimitadas veces, tantas veces como sea posible, devolviendo según sea necesario (codicioso)
- `de` -> coincide con los caracteres "de"  literalmente (distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas)
- `$` -> afirma la posición al final de una línea

La sintaxis `(?P<Nombre>...)` en los grupos de captura define un grupo con nombre. Dicho nombre es usado por pandas como nombre de columna.

Comment: Como dice @Kershing Flores esta respuesta es: ¡Genial!. Tengo que estudiar las expresiones regulares. Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Solución con "find":

```
lines = data[0].tolist()

rankings_2 = []
restaurants_2 = []
chefs_2 = []
countries_2 = []

for line in lines:
    rankings_2.append(line[:line.rfind(". ")])
    restaurants_2.append(line[line.find(". ")+2:line.rfind(" de")])
    chefs_2.append(line[line.find("de ")+3:line.rfind(" (")])
    countries_2.append(line[line.find("(")+1:line.rfind(")")])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'Ranking': rankings_2,
  'Restaurant': restaurants_2,
  'Chef': chefs_2,
  'País': countries_2
})

df2
```

Output:

```
Ranking Restaurant  Chef    País
0   1   Mirazur Mauro Colagreco Francia
1   2   Restaurante Noma 2.0    René Redzepi    Dinamarca
2   3   Asador Etxebarri    Víctor Arguinzoniz  España
3   4   Gaggan  Gaggan Anand    Tailandia
4   5   Geranium    Rasmus Kofoed   Dinamarca
5   6   Central Virgilio Martinez   Perú
6   7   Mugaritz    Andoni Luis Aduriz  España
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @FJSevilla es simplemente genial, con la expresión regular haces todo el trabajo de una vez. Si no comprendes muy bien las expresiones regulares también puedes ir jugando con los split

```
lines = [
  '1. Mirazur de Mauro Colagreco (Francia)',
  '2. Restaurante Noma 2.0 de René Redzepi (Dinam...',
  '3. Asador Etxebarri de Víctor Arguinzoniz (Esp...',
  '4. Gaggan de Gaggan Anand (Tailandia)',
  '5. Geranium de Rasmus Kofoed (Dinamarca)',
  '6. Central de Virgilio Martinez (Perú)',
  '7. Mugaritz de Andoni Luis Aduriz (España)',
  '8. L’Arpege de Alain Passard (Francia)'
]
rankings = []
restaurants = []
chefs = []
countries = []

for line in lines:
  rankings.append(line.split('.')[0])
  restaurants.append(' '.join(line.split(' de ')[0].split(' ')[1:]))
  chefs.append(line.split(' de ')[1].split(' (')[0])
  countries.append(line.split(' de ')[1].split(' (')[1].replace(')', ''))

data = pandas.DataFrame({
  'ranking': rankings,
  'restaurants': restaurants,
  'chefs': chefs,
  'countries': countries
})
```

Aunque te recomiendo considerar muchísimo la respuesta de @FJSevilla y dedicarle un rato a las expresiones regulares.

Comment: He probado tu respuesta tal y como está y funciona. El problema es que no tengo las entradas en una lista sino en un dataframe.

Lo que hice es convertirlo a lista:  ``lines = data[0].tolist() `` .

Y luego aplicar tu código pero me sale el siguiente error:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-84cc75c4345b> in <module>

---> 10   countries.append(line.split(' de ')[1].split(' (')[1].replace(')', ''))

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Y al parecer el error se da en el segundo split de la línea: countries.append(line.split(' de ')[1].split(' (')[1].replace(')', ''))

Comment: Seguro es porque al momento de hacer el split el arreglo no tiene mas de un elemento. ¿Todo los elementos del dataframe tienen la misma estructura!?

Comment: Así es. Acabo de hacerlo con el método "find". Chequealo más abajo, lo he publicado como una respuesta.